# Angular $scope not set after factory returned data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

I have an Angular app with a factory and a controller:

```
.factory('dogeFactory', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    var dogeResource = $resource("https://dogechain.info/api/v1/address/balance/:address");
    return {
        balance: function(address){
            return dogeResource.get({address: address}).$promise
            .then(
                function(data){ 
                    return data.balance;
                }
            );
        },
    }
}])

.controller('TwoController', function($scope, dogeFactory){
    $scope.balance = dogeFactory.balance('D8EyEfuNsfQ3root9R3ac54mMcLmoNBW6q').then(
    function(data){
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    });
```

The `console.log(data);` in the controller shows the correct data, but when I call `{{balance}}` in the view, it shows `{}`.

[Here is the issue on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/neptune001/rmvhsuc1/)

Why `$scope.balance` isn't set properly with the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `balance` is async, you can't directly return from it. You need to set your scope value in the `then` callback.

```
dogeFactory.balance('D8EyEfuNsfQ3root9R3ac54mMcLmoNBW6q').then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    $scope.balance = data;
});
```